# showing hidden content based on which slide is active of a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to show hidden content based off of which carousel item is active. Even if you tell me how to return just the active class element id would help alot.

Comment: this needs code example for anyone to help

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to documentation you have some events to capture carousel slide http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

You can place this following script inside that event...

```js
var liActive = $('#carousel-example-generic').find('ol').find('li.active')[0];
console.log("li element:", liActive);

var slideActive = $(liActive).data('slide-to');
console.log('data-slide-to active:', slideActive);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This only returns the first one, i need one that updates as it changes